# Polymer: Instance polymer element from another element

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadowbox, web-component

I'm wondering how could I **instance** a Polymer element when I click on **another** element. Is there a way to instance *window-base* from *dock-icon*? (code down). I though I could use the constructor every element has but I can't figure out how this works. How could I pass a variable to that constructor.

Code of the two elements involved:

```
<polymer-element name="dock-icon" attributes="name" on-click="{{click}}">
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dock-icon.css">
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('dock-icon', {
        name: "",
        click: function (event, detail, sender) {
            alert(this.name);
            //instance <window-base> and pass name parameter
        }
    });
</script>
```

Polymer element that has to be instanced

```
<polymer-element name="window-base" attributes="name height width left top">
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="window-base.css">
    <div id="box">
        <header id="header"><h2>{{name}}</h2></header>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('window-base', {
        name: "name",
        //more stuff here
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've finally found a solution to my problem so I'll post here what I did in case someone can benefit from it. I end up using the pure javascript way to instance an element.                               `code` var container = document.getElementsByTagName("window-container")[0];                                                     var window=document.createElement("window-base"); window.setAttribute("name",this.name);                              container.appendChild(window);  `code`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be straightforward as:

```
var el = document.createElement('window-base');
el.name = 'some name';
```

Comment: Thanks! I discovered this was possible a couple of days ago. I should have post the solution here.